# How does Svelte's reactivity actually trigger?

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to understand Svelte's reactivity.

From what I see in the following code, if 2 variables are assigned within a `$: {...}` block, Svelte considers those variables to be 'related', and any change in one will cause all `$:` lines with the other to trigger. **Even though, as we see in the code, both variables are completely unrelated and even the line of code that assigns them never executes (`if (false) {...}` block)**.

```html
<script>
  let objA = {some: 'thing'}
  let objB = {other: 'stuff'}
  // this console.log() is triggered!!
  $: console.log('This shouldnt trigger because objA is never modified or reassigned', objA)
  $: if (false) {
    objB = objB
    objA = objA
    }
</script>

<select bind:value={objB.other}>
    <option value="x">x</option>
    <option value="y">y</option>
</select>
```

Is my understanding correct? Because I originally thought reactivity only cascaded if the variables actually affected the value of other, but it seems that's not true. And Svelte Doc's says nothing on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Svelte analyzes assignments and usage.

If a reactive block contains a variable in the current scope, it will re-evaluate the block once said variable is invalidated. Invalidation happens whenever a variable (or sub-property of it) is assigned. If a dependency is detected, dependent variables are also invalidated.

Logic is not analyzed, so the `if (false)` is not considered.

Your observation that dependencies between variables are created here appears to be accurate, though this is not documented anywhere as far as I know. Maybe an issue should be opened that the docs should be more explicit about the rules being used when evaluating reactive statements.

My understand is that it simply follows:

1. `objA` is assigned in this block.
2. `objA` and `objB` are used in this block.
3. `objA` could depend on `objA`/`objB`.

Which makes the analysis less complex, e.g. you do not have to worry about intermediary variables:

```js
$: {
  const x = objB;
  objA = x;
}
```